# converting string to integer value

Tags: php, network-programming, unix, mathematical-optimization

having the string 
010100

Nowing that this is in hex. How would you obtain the resulting values of:

```
id = 4;
part = 1;
setting = 0;
increment=0;
```

Knowing that in this string id should be a 10 bit value, part a 6 bit value, setting a 2 bit value, **increment with 6 bits** how would you generate the string ?

Thank you for any help.

SORRY, missed the value **increment** for this to make more sense...

Comment: You could possibly check out http://php.net/unpack and bitmasks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
//      123456789012345612123456
$str = '000001010110000111000111';
//              21    33 3     7
$id = base_convert(substr($str, 0, 10), 2, 10);
$part = base_convert(substr($str, 10, 6), 2, 10);
$setting = base_convert(substr($str, 16, 2), 2, 10);
$increment = base_convert(substr($str, 18, 6), 2, 10);
echo "id = $id\npart = $part\nsetting = $setting\nincrement = $increment\n";
```

**Output:**

```
id = 21
part = 33
setting = 3
increment = 7
```